# ERROR: Conf apache2-doc does not exist! When installing libpng12-0

Tags: dpkg

For some reason I'm getting a weird error when trying to install libpng12-0 from a .deb file.

Command:

```
dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb; apt-get install -f
```

Error:

```
Setting up apache2 (2.4.25-3+deb9u2) ...
info: Executing deferred 'a2enconf apache2-doc' for package apache2-doc
ERROR: Conf apache2-doc does not exist!
dpkg: error processing package apache2 (--configure): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing: apache2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

apache2-doc is installed (checked with: `apt policy apache2-doc`)

The .deb file I'm trying to install: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libpng12-0/download

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Purge and reinstall package, maybe the installation was corrupt.

```
apt-get purge apache2-doc
apt-get install apache2-doc
dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb; apt-get install -f
```